# Regex to find keys in JSON

Tags: json, regex, grep

I want to match keys in JSON string on linux shell grep. My objective is to remove JSON keys so that values would come out in CSV. Please help me with regex. I tried `"(.*?)":`

```
{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2"}
```

But above regex matches "field1": and then "value1","field2":

So basically it shouldn't match groups containing comma. I know this should be done in python or java. But I want to avoid deployment of application on that specific server. Also internet access has been revoked from this server and many othe restrictions so I cannot install any new tools or commands. Is it possible?

Comment: can downvoter explain the reason?

Comment: Try with `"([^"]*?)":`

Comment: I did not down-vote, possible reason could be `grep` is not the _right_ tool to parse a `JSON` file which is non-syntax aware, use a more specific tool meant for this, like `jq`

Comment: @Inian check my edited question again. I cant install softwares on this server. So I must work with what I have

Comment: Anyone who's downvoting first read my question carefully. I can't use any other approach other than regex in grep or sed

Comment: Did you double checked absense of python, perl, etc? `grep` or `sed` only? Fast github search founds bash-based JSON parsers (for ex. https://github.com/dominictarr/JSON.sh) or awk-based (https://github.com/step-/JSON.awk).

Comment: @Nikolay I know there are tons of tools on github. However, I cannot copy or download anything on those servers now due to some client restrictions. Doing otherwise will take a lot of time. Python, perl is not there on server

Comment: @Shades88 I don't know why your question is downvoted. I upvoted anyway.

Comment: @horcrux your regex helped me, thanks a lot man. you should put it in answer

Comment: How do you access the machine? If you can execute a grep command inside a shell, you can evaluate JSON.sh the same way and use it to parse the data.

Comment: are you able to install `jq` tool?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try the following regex:

```
"([^"]+?)"\s*:
```

It will match any word character that may be between quotes(`" "`) succeed by a `:` (ignoring whitespaces).

### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/09VphV/3)

Comment: Hey, this regex also matches http: if it's present in value.

Comment: @Shades88 I've updated my regex/demo, it may work for url and spaces :)